# Replace text and add to trailing numerical characters as comma separated

Tags: php

I have a string as follows...

`$myString = "2,4,5,8,9,11,Inventory2,Inventory3,Inventory4,Inventory5"`

I want to search for anything with the prefix "Inventory" and replace with a number which is dynamically generated. As an example say the number is "24 it will add 24 to 2 making the first matching result 26.

The end result should turn the string to `"2,4,5,8,9,11,26,27,28,29"`

I know how to search and replace inventory however I am unable to figure out how to add to the trailing number. Thoughts?

```
$str = "$comma_separated"; 
$expression = 'Inventory(\*),'; 
$replace = '24'; 
$newStr = str_replace("Inventory","24","$comma_separated");
```

I am using a static number for testing purposes

Comment: Show us the code that removes the word `Inventory` and we will see if we can sort your number issue out using it

Comment: `$str = "$comma_separated";
      $expression = 'Inventory(\*),';
      $replace = '24';

      $newStr = str_replace("Inventory","24","$comma_separated");
`

I am using a static number for testing purposes.

Comment: Next time someone asks to see more, add it to the question (using the edit link). Nodoby can read code in a comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`preg_replace_callback`](https://php.net/preg_replace_callback) can do it:

```
$v = 24;
$myString = "2,4,5,8,9,11,Inventory2,Inventory3,Inventory4,Inventory5";
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/Inventory(\d+)/',
    function ($m) use ($v) {
        return $v + $m[1];
    },
    $myString
);
```